# Website Loading Content from Malicious Sites

Tags: malware, wordpress

I own a website. Now today I find that when I load the site, Chrome shows "waiting for xxx.com" and some other unknown sites.
I never added content or links from these sites.
The website is running on WordPress.
What can be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Lots of possible reasons... does it happen in other browsers to? What's in your access log and error log? Is WordPress using all the security patches?

Comment: Have you tried it on other computers?

Comment: @S.L.Barth IE Does not show details when loading,in chrome i can see in bottom left corner.Let me check with other browsers.Wordpress is not up to date,since there are some problems with the plugins,so i keep it that way. Where can i see the error log?

Comment: @NeilSmithline Let me try and get back.just a min

Comment: @NeilSmithline It does not show in chrome/firefox on my pc.

Comment: Might your have some malware on your Mac?

Comment: Location of the error log depends on your OS and web server. For Apache on Linux it's in /var/log/apache2 . For IIS on Windows it seems to be visible from  Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer (according to web search).

Comment: @S.L.Barth It does not show on my pc browser,but it shows on my laptop.Please see previous comment

Comment: @NeilSmithline Its not a Mac,its a  windows 8.1 laptop.I have bit defender installed.

Comment: My bad about the Mac. Must have confused another question <blush>. Still sounds something on the computer. A bad browser plugin or something bitdefender is missing.

Comment: Wild guess, could it be an XSS attempt requesting something upon page load, possibly a deface attempt?

Comment: This looks like a local variable problem. If ti doesn't happen on other computers then it means you have a virus on your laptop. I'd check to make sure your DNS option in computer settings isn't tampered with(easy showing of a virus) and that you run a scan using a few anti viruses.

Comment: @RobertMennell Yeah.. there was a browser redirection malware on my lap.Now its fixed.

Comment: @techno Glad I could help. Might e a good idea to close this question then since it's been fixed.

Comment: @Robert Mennell actually this had been issued long back.thanks for your help anyway :).I will close the question.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your website is hacked / compromised and the attacker must have injected some malicious script into your website index for monetary gain through ads or for other profits. There is also a possibility that the source website from where it is loading the content is also hacked / compromised. What I can suggest you is:

1. It is necessary to identify the malcious code injected into the scripts for which you need some knowledge of php and security. The malicious code can be hidden anywhere in the php file , in the javascript file, in the images (.png|.jpg|.gif), .htaccess file or any file extension on the server or it can be due to vulnerable plugins that you have installed in wordpress.
2. I would suggest you to create a backup of the complete website, Freshly install the latest version of Wordpress and then restore / import the db (there is still the possibility of the code hidden in the database but I have found very rare cases where this happens)

More details can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked).

Comment: Thanks,but this issue is only occurs on my laptop.Please see the comments on the question.

Comment: @techno Can you please provide us with the _screenshots_ ? or share html code of the index page (the page which loads when your website is visited) on pastie or pastebin **don't forget to remove your host name**.

Answer (score -1):

Open your browser's development window, and look for requests in the *network* tab. This could be a WordPress plugin loading something from a 3rd party, it could be your browser preloading links or it could be one of your browsers add-ons/plugins/extensions loading something. It's nearly impossible to say with the information provided.

You could also try viewing the source of the page in question, although requests may also be triggered by scripts located elsewhere on the site.

Good hunting!

Comment: Why was this voted down?